# What is the meaning of "lint" in the command -Xlint=unchecked?

Tags: java, javac

What does "`lint`" in the flag `-Xlint=unchecked` for `javac` stand for? Since it deals with generic types, one would expect something like `-Xgenerics=unchecked` or so!

Comment: Thanks to those who answered. Didn’t expect a mere flag to represent  Lint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It derives from a C language optional compiling tool with the purpose of detecting 'suspicious' behaviors in your code.  It has become a standard way to refer to this kind of static code analysis

Comment: I will always remember my C compiler in university days which warned me about a 'suspicious' cast I had made... and it was indeed suspicious!! :D

Answer (score 10):

It's a tip-o-the-hat to the [programming history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29):

> In computer programming, **lint** was the name originally given to a particular program that flagged some suspicious and non-portable constructs (likely to be bugs) in C language source code. The term is now applied generically to tools that flag suspicious usage in software written in any computer language.
>
> Lint first appeared (outside of Bell Labs) in the seventh version (V7) of the Unix operating system in 1979.

Comment: You and Jorge posted at around the same time. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am accepting Jorge’s answer, but want to let you know that what you posted was very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

"[Lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29)" refers to the process of analyzing source code to locate common programming mistakes, unsafe coding practices, or the like. Options that begin with `-Xlint` change the way `javac` lints.

Answer (score 1):

Lint is the name of the command, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)